# Mpi Bcast Error while using Calcul Canada

Tags: macos, mpi, slurm

I am trying to run a calculation on the calcul canada remote site from my MAC. this is the input file run.sh I am using:
`#!/bin/sh`

```
#SBATCH --nodes=4

#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=32
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=2000M
#SBATCH --account=def-jkopysci
module load quantumespresso/6.4.1
srun -n 128 pw.x -i < espresso.scf.in > sample.out`
```

After a few minutes, it outputs a slurm along with an output file. The output file is good but incomplete (a few iterations happen but then it stops). This is what the slurm contains:

```
`    [blg7239:222904] *** An error occurred in MPI_Bcast
[blg7239:222904] *** reported by process [47353251107131,62]
[blg7239:222904] *** on communicator MPI COMMUNICATOR 29 SPLIT FROM 26
[blg7239:222904] *** MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
[blg7239:222904] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[blg7239:222904] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 62 seconds for job step to finish.
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 8210518.0 ON blg7131 CANCELLED AT 2020-05-28T21:37:12 ***
srun: error: blg9414: tasks 64-95: Killed
srun: error: blg9415: tasks 96-127: Killed
srun: error: blg7131: tasks 0-31: Killed
srun: error: blg7239: tasks 32-61,63: Killed
srun: error: blg7239: task 62: Exited with exit code 15`
```

why is this happening and how can I fix it? Please help!!!

Comment: Try to `export OMPI_MCA_coll=^tuned` before invoking `srun` and see if it helps.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thank you! I have a Mac though. Do I just write this in terminal or in the run.sh file?

Comment: In your script before `srun`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet It worked fine until the time limit was done. after 24 hours (the time limit) it stopped but I opened the output file and it was empty!

Comment: The workaround has obvious performance impact, so that could explain why your job does not complete within the time limit. I would try to investigate if the program is doing actual progress (via a debugger, padb or other tools) though.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Do you know an easy way I can find out if the program is doing actual progress? Thank you!!

Comment: collect the stacks via `padb`

Comment: could you explain to me how to do that? Thank you @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: http://padb.pittman.org.uk/

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet the export OMPI_MCA_coll=^tuned did not work. Do you have other ideas? Thank you!